# Prob. 4(a), Sec. 13 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Any necessary and sufficient conditions for a union of topologies to be a topology?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a non-empty set, let $$\left\{ \ \mathscr{T}_\alpha \ \colon \ \alpha \in J \ \right\}$$ be a non-empty collection of topologies on $X$, and let $$ \mathscr{T} \colon= \bigcup_{\alpha\in J} \mathscr{T}_\alpha.$$

Then $\mathscr{T}$ may or may not be a topology on $X$.

What is (are) the necessary and sufficient condition(s) for $\mathscr{T}$ to be a topology on $X$?

As a sufficient condition, I can think of the following:

For any $\alpha$ and $\beta \in J$ such that $\alpha \neq \beta$, we must have either $\mathscr{T}_\alpha \subset \mathscr{T}_\beta$ or  $\mathscr{T}_\beta \subset \mathscr{T}_\alpha$.

Am I right?

Is the above condition necessary also?

Can we formulate other conditions that are either necessary or sufficient, or both for $\mathscr{T}$ to be a topology?

Can we come up with any condition(s) on the set $X$ that turn out to be either necessary or sufficient, or both, for $\mathscr{T}$ to be a topology?

Comment: I don't think your condition is sufficient. Let $X = \mathbb N =\{0,1,2,\cdots\}$.
Index an increasing sequence of topologies $\mathcal T_k$, each generated by the sets $\{1\},\cdots, \{k\}$, for $k\ge1$. Then the set $\mathbb N^+=\{1,2,\cdots\}$ is not in the union of $\mathcal T_k$, while $\mathbb N^+ = \cup_{k\ge  1} \{k\}$.

Comment: I can only think about some "stupid" conditions: if $U_1,U_2\in\tau$ then there are $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in J$ such that $U_i\in\tau_{\alpha_i}$. If $\tau$ is topology, there must be $\alpha_3\in J$ such that $U_1\cap U_2\in\tau_{\alpha_3}$. The same for arbitrary unions. This would be the conditions.

Comment: @peterag I didn't get your solution.

Comment: No solution, sorry - only a counter-example... Each $\{k\}$ is an open set (i.e., element) of $\mathcal T_k$, $k\ge 1$. Write $\mathcal T = \cup_{k\ge 1}\mathcal T_k$. So $\{k\}\in \mathcal T$, for all $k\ge 1$. If $\mathcal T$ were a topology, then $\mathbb N^+= \cup_{k\ge 1} \{k\}$ would also be an element of $\mathcal T$, as topologies are closed under unions. But that would mean that $\mathbb N^+ \in \mathcal T_k$, for some $k\ge 1$. But it's not; this is why I avoided the $0$ and used $\mathbb N^+$  - by contrast $\mathbb N$ is of course a member of every $\mathcal T_k$.

Comment: @peterag for any $k =1, 2, 3, \ldots$, how can the collection $\left\{ \ \{1\}, \ldots, \{k\} \ \right\}$ generate a topology on the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$? You see the topology has to contain the set $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ itself.

Comment: By "$\{1\},\cdots \{k\}$ generating the topology $\mathcal T_k$" (where $k \ge 1$) , I mean that $\mathcal T_k$ is the smallest topology on $X =\mathbb N$ that contains the sets $\{1\},\cdots \{k\}$. In particular, for free, every $\mathcal T_k$ always contains $X$ and the empty set. On the other hand, no $\mathcal T_k$ contains $\mathbb  N^+$. OK?

Comment: In other words, $\mathcal T_k=\{U\subseteq \mathbb N: U=\mathbb N\text{ or }U\subseteq\{1,\dots,k\}\}.$ Then $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}\mathcal T_k$ is $\{U\subseteq\mathbb N:U=\mathbb N\text{ or }U\text{ is finite }\}$ and that is not a topology.

Comment: @bof - you were neater and clearer than I was...

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked me to answer here: http://dbfin.com/topology/munkres/chapter-2/section-13-basis-for-a-topology/problem-5-solution/#comment-2456653263.

**Your sufficient condition is not in fact sufficient**

Indeed, let $X=\mathbb{R}$, and consider topology $\mathcal{T}_n=\{\emptyset,X,I_1,\ldots,I_n=(-1,1-\tfrac{1}{n})\}$. Each $\mathcal{T}_n$ is clearly a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but their union contains every $I_n$, but not their countable union $\cup_n I_n = (-1,1)$.

**A general (not very useful) necessary and sufficient condition**

So, given an indexed family of topologies $\{\mathcal{T}_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in J}$ on $X$, the question is, when $\mathcal{T}=\cup_{\alpha\in J} \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ is a topology. Let us check all conditions.

1. The empty set and $X$ are in $\mathcal{T}$ because they are in each topology.
2. Given $U_\beta\in\mathcal{T}$, $\beta\in K$, we need $\cup_{\beta\in K} U_\beta\in \mathcal{T}$.

For every $\alpha\in J$, let $S(\alpha)$ be the set of indexes $\beta$ such that $U_\beta\in \mathcal{T}_\alpha$. Then, $\cup_{\beta\in K}U_\beta = \cup_{\alpha\in J}\cup_{\beta\in S(\alpha)}U_\beta$, but $\cup_{\beta\in S(\alpha)}U_\beta\in \mathcal{T}_\alpha$.

3. Similarly for (finite) intersections, $\cap_{n=1}^N U_n = \cap_{\alpha\in J}\cap_{\beta\in S(\alpha)}U_\beta$, but $\cap_{\beta\in S(\alpha)}U_\beta\in \mathcal{T}_\alpha$ because $\cup_\alpha S(\alpha)=\{1,\ldots,N\}$ is finite.

Therefore, we conclude, that a **sufficient** condition is as follows:

```
arbitrary unions and finite intersections of sets
from pairwise different topologies must belong to
some topologies in the family.
```

This condition is also, clearly, **necessary**.

This condition is not very useful, but about to be the best one can find in general. It can also be useful in specific cases, such as those below.

**A specific trivial case**

If $X$ has two elements, then the union of an arbitrary family of topologies on $X$ is a topology on $X$.

**Finite case**

Suppose now $X$ is arbitrary, but the family of topologies contains a finite number of topologies, $\mathcal{T}_n$, $1\le n\le N$. Then, we have the following criterion: $\mathcal{T}=\cup_n\mathcal{T}_n$ is a topology iff for every $U\in\mathcal{T}_i$ and $V\in\mathcal{T}_j$, $U\cup V$ and $U\cap V$ belong to some $\mathcal{T}_k$ and $\mathcal{T}_{k'}$, respectively.

Note, that this condition holds for the above example of topologies on $\mathbb{R}$, even though their union is not a topology. This is, of course, because this criterion is for a finite number of topologies only, and there we have a countable number of topologies.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, a "necessary and sufficient condition for" some statement $\;P\;$ is a statement that is *equivalent* to $\;P\;$.  And presumably that equivalent statement is simpler, or more useful, or more explicit, than $\;P\;$.

For this specific question, let's try the calculational approach.$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
\newcommand{\false}{\text{false}}
\newcommand{\a}{\alpha}
\newcommand{\b}{\beta}
\newcommand{\c}{\gamma}
\newcommand{\V}{\mathcal V}
\newcommand{\W}{\mathcal W}
\newcommand{\T}[1]{{\mathcal T}_{#1}}
\newcommand{\istop}[2]{#1\text{ is a topology on }#2}
$

We are given a non-empty set $\;X\;$, and a non-empty set $\;J\;$ which is used as an 'index set'.  To avoid visual noise, we will implicitly assume that $\;\a,\b,\c \in J\;$.  We are given a family $\;\T{-}\;$ where for every $\;\alpha\;$, $\;\istop{\T{\a}}{X}\;$.

The question is now: find an equivalent for the statement
$$
\tag{0}
\istop{\langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle}{X}
$$

Let's also make explicit the definition of a topology:
\begin{align}
\tag{1}
& \istop{\V}{X} \;\equiv\;
\\ & \qquad
\tag{1a}
X \in \V
\\ & \qquad \land\;
\tag{1b}
\langle \forall A,B : A \in \V \land B \in \V : A \cap B \in \V \rangle
\\ & \qquad \land\;
\tag{1c}
\langle \forall \W : W \subseteq \V : \bigcup \W \in \V \rangle
\end{align}

Now, let's try to calculate an equivalent for $\ref{0}$.

---

Using definition $\ref{1}$ we can write $\ref{0}$ as $\ref{0a} \land \ref{0b} \land \ref{0c}$, and we will rewrite those three parts in turn.

First part $\ref{a}$ of the definition:
$$\calc
    \tag{0a}
    X \in \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle
\op=\hint{definition of $\;\cup\;$}
    \langle \exists \a :: X \in \T{\a} \rangle
\op=\hint{each $\;\T{\a}\;$ is a topology, using $\ref{1a}$}
    \langle \exists \a :: \true \rangle
\op=\hint{the index set $\;J\;$ is not empty}
    \true
    \tag{A}
\endcalc$$
So this part is always satisfied.

For part $\ref{b}$ we get:
$$\calc
    \tag{0b}
    \langle \forall A,B : A \in \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle \land B \in \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle : A \cap B \in \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle \rangle
\op=\hint{definition of $\;\cup\;$, three times; rename dummies}
    \langle \forall A,B : \langle \exists \a :: A \in \T{\a} \rangle \land \langle \exists \b :: B \in \T{\b} \rangle : \langle \exists \c :: A \cap B \in \T{\c} \rangle \rangle
\op=\hint{logic: $\;\langle \forall x : \langle \exists y :: P \rangle : Q \rangle\;$ is equivalent to $\;\langle \forall x,y : P : Q \rangle\;$, twice}
    \langle \forall A,B,\a,\b : A \in \T{\a} \land B \in \T{\b} : \langle \exists \c :: A \cap B \in \T{\c} \rangle \rangle
    \tag{B}
\endcalc$$
In words: *For any two open sets in any of the topologies (from the family), their intersection is in some topology (in the family).*

Finally part $\ref{c}$, where we can do even less:
$$\calc
    \tag{0c}
    \langle \forall \W : \W \subseteq \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle : \bigcup \W \in \langle \cup \a :: \T{\a} \rangle \rangle
\op=\hint{definition of $\;\subseteq$; definition of $\;\cup\;$, twice}
    \langle \forall \W : \langle \forall Z : Z \in \W : \langle \exists \a :: Z \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle : \langle \exists \a :: \bigcup \W \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle
    \tag{C}
\endcalc$$
In words: *For any collection of sets, where each is open in some topology (in the family), the union of those sets is in some topology (in the family).*

Combining the above, we've proven that $\ref{B} \land \ref{C}$ is an equivalent, and more explicit, version of $\ref{0}$.

---

Without more knowledge about the family of topologies $\;\T{-}\;$, it is not possible to go any further.

The only thing one could still do is to rewrite the last line of part $\ref{c}$ above, as follows:
$$\calc
    \tag{C}
    \langle \forall \W : \langle \forall Z : Z \in \W : \langle \exists \a :: Z \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle : \langle \exists \a :: \bigcup \W \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle
 \op=\hints{set theory: introduce a choice function}
       \hint{-- to convert the nested $\;\langle \forall \ldots \rangle\;$ to a $\;\langle \exists \ldots \rangle\;$}
     \langle \forall \W : \langle \exists f : f \in \W \to J : \langle \forall Z : Z \in \W : Z \in \T{f(Z)} \rangle \rangle : \langle \exists \a :: \bigcup \W \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle 
\op=\hint{logic: $\;\langle \forall x : \langle \exists y :: P \rangle : Q \rangle\;$ is equivalent to $\;\langle \forall x,y : P : Q \rangle\;$}
     \langle \forall \W, f : f \in \W \to J \;\land\; \langle \forall Z : Z \in \W : Z \in \T{f(Z)} \rangle : \langle \exists \a :: \bigcup \W \in \T{\a} \rangle \rangle
\endcalc$$
But that does not seem useful in most contexts...